# What does java.exe do in Windows\System32

Tags: windows, java, path

I found that `java.exe` file is located in `Windows\System32` directory and has precedence over my selected java in `Program Files` directory (due to `PATH` components order).

I have tried deleting this file yet it comes back after reboot.

How to remove this file permanently and use Java version I want?

Comment: I ask myself the same thing, broke my flow when javac was 1.8 and java was 1.7. Here's another explanation I found: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/why-is-java-under-program-files-and-windows/58cc27a9-a4cd-4d5f-baf6-9c4fae780828